# Нужна ли запятая перед "с последующим"?

Tags: пунктуация

**"Перед началом работы увеличение объема закваски осуществляют путем внесения в нее питательной смеси с температурой 47 – 49 °C в соотношении 1:4(,) с последующим выдерживанием при температуре 36 – 40 °C до кислотности 14 – 18 град".** Нужно ли ставить запятую в данном случае?

Comment: Что такое "град"? Не нашёл такой единицы измерения.

Comment: Град - это сокращение от градусы, используется в спецлитературе

Comment: **Стася**, а при выдерживании _"при температуре 36 – 40 °C до кислотности 14 – 18 град"_ объём закваски увеличивается или нет? Если увеличивается, то можно без запятой. А ежели не увеличивается, то лучше запятую сохранить, чтобы разорвать связь с началом предложения: _"Перед началом работы увеличение объема закваски осуществляют... (?) выдерживанием при температуре... до кислотности..."_  А лучше, по возможности,  отредактировать предложение.

Comment: Кислотность в градусах? Хм... Тогда лучше полностью написать или хоть точку поставить, нет?

Comment: slava1947. Эта информация (цитата) из нормативного документа. Просто не могу понять, почему там запятая стоит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обстоятельственный оборот **не обособляется**, так как **не имеет уточняющего значения, а входит в основное сообщение** (идет перечень технологических операций).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна: *путём внесения смеси с последующим выдерживанием...*

Начало и конец предложения и большая его длина не могут быть причиной для постановки запятой.

Comment: Засомневалась, потому что в нормативном документе стоит запятая.